# Collisions in hash table - Is this table wrong?

Tags: hash-tables

I have the following hash table with hashcodes being quadratic numbers.

[image: Table]

Why do 0, 16, and 64 have different number of collisions when they map to the same number (line %16). Also how is it possible for 64 to have 6 collisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here collisions means the number of (occupied) positions visited before finding a free spot and placing the number.

64 goes to 0(occupied by 0) - 1(by 1) - 2(by 16) - 3(by 49) - 4(by 4) - 5(by 36) - 6(bingo)

The table is consistent with linear hashing and stepsize $1$.